# what is the flow of execution in this control structure

Tags: android, if-statement, ondraw

```
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {

         if (x == getWidth() - bmp.getWidth()) 
         {
                xSpeed = -1;
         }

         if (x == 0) 
         {
               xSpeed = 1;
         }
         x = x + xSpeed;
         canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
         canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x , 10, null);
     }
```

Let's say `x = 0` and `xSpeed = 1`,how does it work
Please explain this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flow of excution is always top to buttom.So you can see your code how it will execute.

Comment: If x=1, then it will calculate the value getWidth()-bmp.getWidth().If it is 1 then xSpeed=-1 will execute.If getWidth()-bmp.getWidth() is not equal to 1 then x=x+xSpeed will be excuted and also 2 more codes after it will execute.

Comment: lets take getwidth=10,bmp.getwidth=2.so when x reach to 8 xSpeed=-1,will execute when x will reach to 7 then...? because {getwidth()-bmp.getwidth()} is always a constant.

Comment: See when x value will be same as getWidth()-bmp.getWidth() then  xSpeed=-1 will excute else it will not execute.Now you can accept my answer.

Comment: when x will reach to 7 what then...? because {getwidth()-bmp.getwidth()} is always a constant.

Comment: I know that is constant as you said before.So it will only execute once when x will be 8 else no.If you want it get execute with different value of x then you should write code accordingly.

Comment: thankx dude i got my ans as xSpeed now contain the value -1, so after every iteration it will substract 1 from x value.....

Comment: It is my pleasure to help you.